# Why modal materializecss do not open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I`m write app with react and materializecss, but modal window do not open

import:

```
import 'materialize-css';
import options from 'materialize-css';
import M from 'materialize-css';
```

js for modal:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
});
```

modal:

```
<a className="red waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Удалить аккаунт</a>
<div id="modal1" className="modal">
   <div className="modal-content">
      <h4>Внимание!</h4>
      <p>Убедитесь, что вы действительно хотите удалить свой аккаунт, все данные об аккаунте будут утеряны и восстановить аккаунт невозможно</p>
   </div>
   <div className="modal-footer">
      <a href="/auth" className="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" onClick={buttonDeleteAccount}>Удалить аккаунт</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use proper React code, and probably this instead: https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize

Answer (score 1):

Take the undeclared `options` variable out:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
});
```

Always check the console first!

Comment: console.log(instaces) return nothing, and I test without options, but do not open, console.log(elems, options) return nothing

Comment: I didn't say log to the console - I said check the console for error messages. If you initialise with an undeclared options variable it will throw an error.